# SQL query is producing an error which I can't solve

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following tables which im querying:

```
categories
  -id
  -name
  -parent_id
  -last

products2categories
  -id
  -product_id
  -category_id
```

What im trying to do is to get the record's `category name` and `category id` which the `product_id` in the table `products2categories` is 10 and `last` in the table `categories` is 1

this is the query that i've tried to execute:

```
SELECT `categories.id`,`categories.name` 
FROM `categories` 
JOIN `products2categories` 
ON `categories.id` = `products2categories.category_id`
WHERE `categories.last` = 1 
AND `products2categories.product_id`= 10
```

I've been returned with the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'categories.last' in 'where clause'
```

To demonstrate what I'm trying to get:

```
categories
  -id          8
  -name        "my_name"
  -parent_id   0
  -last        1

products2categories
  -id          1
  -product_id  10
  -category_id 1
```

I want to get as a result the ID of `8` and the name of "my_name" but it has to be based on the table products2categories, cause one product, can have more than one category which it's related to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you remove all the backticks from you query. It should work fine then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are delimiting fields incorrectly. Delimit the table name and column name separately:

```
SELECT `categories`.`id`,`categories`.`name` 
FROM `categories` 
JOIN `products2categories` 
ON `categories`.`id` = `products2categories`.`category_id`
WHERE `categories`.`last` = 1 
AND `products2categories`.`product_id`= 10
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
WHERE `categories.last` = 1
```

with

```
WHERE `categories`.`last` = 1
```

Backticks for escaping column and table names can't be used to escape the combination of table and column. It must be applyed on both.

Answer (score 1):

A quick check of your syntax: `categories.last` shouldn't be `categories`.`last` instead?

Do as same for all other "fields"

Comment: yup! lol never knew this would effect the query, I had to put the ` sign after each table name and field seperately

Comment: @kfirba As *juergen d* explained in its own answer, *backticks* are used to *escape* table/column names. If you write `categories.last` in the context of a `WHERE` clause, MySQL will assume you are referring to a column having that name. This allow you to have columns with *unusual* characters such as dots, spaces, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the backticks around a single identifier:

So

```
`categories.last`
```

should be

```
`categories`.`last`
```

because the table name and the column name are separate identifiers.

In this case, you don't need the backticks at all, by the way, so it should work fine if you remove them, like this:

```
categories.last
```

You need the backticks only for column names containing spaces or some other special characters, and maybe for names that are equal to some reserved words in some circumstances. But as far as I can tell, you don't need them at all in your case, and I don't recall every having had to use them.