# Table name show a syntax error in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I try to create a table with the following name in MySQL it show a syntax error but its not showing any problem if I use the phpmyadmin :

"**attn-cse-a[3-1][mpms][10-8-2013]**"

when I create a same type of table with a different name I am able to do it without any problems..

Any help would be greatly appreciated ..

Comment: Take a look at the MySQL docs about object names/identifiers (database, table, index, column, alias ...) permissible syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html  `If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever you refer to it`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query is producing an error which I can't solve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145459/sql-query-is-producing-an-error-which-i-cant-solve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use illegal characters by escaping them with backticks, but I won't recommend it, since it will only bring you trouble for the rest of the project's lifetime.

Comment: Well, I could create it with the following command:
    mysql> create table `attn-cse-a[3-1][mpms][10-8-2013]`(id CHAR(30));
Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Use back quotes to *wrap* tablename:

```
create table `attn-cse-a[3-1][mpms][10-8-2013]` (...
```

Comment: I would still argue against using this as a table name. Stick to regular alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Have you ever seen MsSql table names? :O