# Is there any serious MySQL naming styleguide?

Tags: mysql, naming

As you can saw in [Table name show a syntax error in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152082/table-name-show-a-syntax-error-in-mysql) question you can define some *particular* tablename (`attn-cse-a[3-1][mpms][10-8-2013]`).

A comment suggest to use only alphanumeric chars as *good* tablename, but this is really a wise choice? What about of "-" and "_"?

**Is there any serious styleguide to MySQL naming of tables, columns, index, etc.?**

I say MySQL because of **big** differences between DB syntax rules of SQL servers, but of course can be a generic SQL naming styleguide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL Reference Manual has a pretty good description of what is allowed:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html

Personally I use a subset of the allowable characters for unquoted identifiers, which the manual describes as follows:

> - Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>
>   - ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar,    underscore)
>   - Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

Restricting that list further, I would not use any of the following in table/column names or other identifiers:

- dollar sign ($)
- extended characters
- [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

So basically that leaves you with alphanumeric characters and underscores, but avoid reserved words.

Comment: +1 for reserved words.A major cause of 1064 errors in questions.